# Simple Rails issue about link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have code that looks like this that I need to understand:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to  t('menubar.yes.okay') , admin_ok_path %></li>
</ul>
```

In this code, what is `menubar.yes.okay` and where is that defined? Similarly, where is `admin_ok_path` defined?

The reason I ask is because I would like to add another menu bar item. And if I write something like

```
<li><%= link_to  t('menubar.yes.no') , admin_ok_no %></li>
```

then I get an error saying `admin_ok_no` is not defined. So, what do I need to define in order to set up this new menu bar option? I have already added a `No: "No"` in my `en.yml`, but it is still the same error. Note that I have checked my routes.rb and there is no definition of `admin_ok_path` however that works fine - it shows up in the menubar.

Comment: `menubar.yes.okay' likely to be defined in config/locales/en.yml. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: admin_ok_path - see your routes file - config/routes.rb http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is defined dynamically. If you run

```
rake routes
```

you will get the all available routes,

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

admin_ok_path is a path helper defined by rails it self for the matching route admin_ok,

if you run rake routes from application route directory, you will get matching admin_ok route.

admin_ok_path will provides a relative url and admin_ok_url will give you the absolute url.

Comment: See updated question. What do I need to define in order to get a new menu bar item working. I already added the update in en.yml and it still has same error

Comment: firstly you need translation to local file as said by Intrepidd, then add route to the routes for admin_ok_no like get "url_path" => "controller#action", :as => admin_ok_no

Answer (score 0):

The helper `t`, short for `I18n.t` is used for internationalization

For example, in config/en.yml, if you have :

```
menubar:
  yes:
    okay: Okay
```

This will write "Okay"

`admin_ok_path` is a dynamically generated helper for the routes path. You can see all of them by running `rake routes`

Comment: See updated question. What do I need to define in order to get a new menu bar item working. I already added the update in en.yml and it still has same error

Answer (score 0):

`t` is short for `translate`. You'll find the localization files in `config/locales` - they're basically YAML files that define strings. See more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

The `admin_path_ok` method is a route helper that returns a path. See your `config/routes.rb` file. More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: See updated question. What do I need to define in order to get a new menu bar item working. I already added the update in en.yml and it still has same error

Comment: admin_path_ok is not defined in my routes.rb

Comment: @CodeGuy if it's being generated by your routes file (i.e. it's not listed when you run `rake routes`), it's probably in a helper file. Check `app/helpers` and see if one of the files there (likely `application_helper.rb`) defines a `admin_path_ok` method. If not, it can be a method defined in a controller (in `app/controllers`), and "exported" using `helper_method :admin_path_ok`

Answer (score 0):

'menubar.yes.okay' likely to be defined in 'config/locales/en.yml'. 
And `rake routes | grep admin` will give you all the routes related to admin.